# Functions takes 2 clicks to show hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a small bit of javascript for showing and hiding a div.

```
function hidefooter(){
var button = document.getElementById('footerbutton');

button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('footerbox');
    if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
}
```

The div starts {display:none;}. I looked around online and could only find people saying it was an html thing. My problem with that was that when i first wrote it the "block" and "none" values were switched and it took 3 clicks to work. Any help would be great.

update: A better explanation. This code does exactly what i want but you have to click twice to get the effect to work. At first i had the "block" and "none" properties switched and it took 3 clicks to get it to work. The footer starts out {display:none;}.  I put it up online so a friend could take a look at it. the url is http://www.miettegoesplaces.com. click on the purple foot button on the right.

update 2: sorted the problem was i was calling the onClick twice. this is the simplified working version.

```
function hideFooter(){

var div = document.getElementById('footerbox');
if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
};
```

thanks for everyones comments and advice.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/uYgRz/ Remember that until you set the style with JS, it won't contain the CSS properties (it's empty to begin with). You'd need getComputedStyle for that.

Comment: Deleted my answer, original code is working fine really should of tested first :)

Comment: @cbuckley, thanks, the jsfiddle you put up works like it was supposed to, so i'll go take a look at my mark up and see if there's anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added click event twice here.

- First, you are calling `onClick` event on button.
- Inside `hidefooter()` function, you have defined `button.onclick = function() {...}`

remove `button.onclick = function() {}` and use like this :

function hidefooter(){

```
var button = document.getElementById('footerbutton');
var div = document.getElementById('footerbox');

if (div.style.display != 'block') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HC3Wy/)

Comment: hey, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I posted the working code up top, it wasn't quite what you wrote, but in the same line of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add "display: none" to your footer's style

Comment: It's already there. That's the first thing i mentioned in the comment below the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle(elem)` for Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome or `elem.currentStyle` for IE

```
var button = document.getElementById('footerbutton');

button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('footerbox');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
    if (style.display !== 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the code that you use to define a button that handles events and add an onClick() event to your button instead
This code will work as you want it

`function hidefooter(){`

```
var div = document.getElementById('footerbox');
if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

`}`

But make sure your button code looks like this:

`<button id="footerbutton" onClick="hidefooter()">Hide Footer</button>`

**Pay attention to onClick="hidefooter()"**

And make sure your div is still `display:none;`

I believe the problem was that you're using the 'hide' button to define what it does and THEN do the hiding work. You should add an event handler that calls the hidefooter() function instead which has nothing but the footer hiding code.

Comment: inline onclick handler? You gotta be kidding.